# flutter : how change the background color of selected text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, epub

i wanna create a epub editor in my app.
I want to be able to change the backgorund color of the selected text when I select a piece of text in an epub.

like this :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution fo this problem?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet :(

Comment: :( Thanks for the response anyway

Comment: Use `action_process_text` library